# When i play video games on full screen i get a bit of a problem

Tags: technical-issues, pc

so to cut to the chase I'll make this about my problem and an image of it.
note that this happens with other games*
when I set my pc games to full screen what i see is a bit pixelated and not 100% clearly what the game is supposed to look like.
and when I print screen the game in full screen and paste it in paint I see that game when it's not pixelated.
i'll include an image to explain a bit of my problem.
[image]

I tried to upload an image for the print screen itself but it's over 2 mb.
I can avoid these by lowering the resolution of the game and playing it on windowed,but I want to see if I can fix it.

Comment: Is your CPU one of the latest i7s ?

Answer (score 3):

What you're explaining happens to me in CS:GO. You are playing in lower resolution than your native desktop resolution:

My screen is 1080 fullHD but as I want higher frame-rate I play cs:go in a slightly lower resolution, so I get exactly what you're having - slightly blurry gameplay.

Have the same resolution, both in game and on windows settings, or play on a lower resolution and pix-elated game-play but higher frame-rate.

As I said my native monitor resolution (and my windows setting is 1920x1080, my overwatch is at 1600x900, so I get this:
[image]